# The plugin specification 'com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:' has a problem:

Tags: java, cucumber, junit, extent

I am getting this error while trying to generate the extent report for cucumber-java and Junit. I am using cucumber version 6.9.1 and grasshopper adapter6. This is my pom.xml file.

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codoid.products/fillo -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codoid.products</groupId>
            <artifactId>fillo</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.python/jython-standalone -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.python</groupId>
            <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.141.59</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.14.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>6.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.python</groupId>
                <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>6.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
                <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/SmokeTestRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Runner File

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

        features = { "Feature"}
        ,glue = { "stepdefinition"
                }
        ,dryRun = false
        ,monochrome = true
        ,plugin = {"pretty",
                "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
                "timeline:test-output-thread/" }
        ,tags = "@SmokeTest12332"
    

public class SmokeTestRunner {

}
```

**Here is the full console error**

````
Could not load plugin class 'com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter'.

Plugin specifications should have the format of PLUGIN[:[PATH|[URI [OPTIONS]]]

Valid values for PLUGIN are: default_summary, html, json, junit, message, null_summary, pretty, progress, rerun, summary, teamcity, testng, timeline, unused, usage

PLUGIN can also be a fully qualified class name, allowing registration of 3rd party plugins. The 3rd party plugin must implement io.cucumber.plugin.Plugin
    at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.createCouldNotLoadClass(PluginOption.java:168)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parsePluginName(PluginOption.java:146)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parse(PluginOption.java:105)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder.addPluginName(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:68)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.addPlugins(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:87)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.parse(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:41)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parsePluginName(PluginOption.java:140)```
````

Comment: please add the error so hat we could help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this. It might help others.

To fix this issues I checked the Maven dependencies. After adding dependencies in Pom.xml, it is not downloading the related dependencies. (It showing that it's downloading but it's not showing in the maven dependencies.)

So I added the external Jar files related to the extent report cucumber adapter 6 in the project. and it start working for me.

Later, fixed the Pom.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is itself very self-explanatory. Your plugin definition is wrong. This

```
"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
```

should not be in `plugin`. As the error message itself states, the valid values are

> Valid values for PLUGIN are: default_summary, html, json, junit,
> message, null_summary, pretty, progress, rerun, summary, teamcity,
> testng, timeline, unused, usage

You can find an example of a valid plugin definition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911963/getting-cucumber-runtime-cucumberexception-couldnt-load-plugin-class-prettty).

Also, you should take a look at your `POM.xml` file. Since you've already mentioned `io.cucumber`, so I don't think there is a need for `info.cukes`.
Also, dependencies that you've added are old. So you should updated the dependencies versions too.